# How to create a drop-down list to filter by groups of values. (Visual Studio Reports 2008)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008

I am a newbie in **Microsoft Visual Studio Reports 2008**.

How can I create a drop-down list to filter by groups of values?

I have a SQL query, which shows the number of solved requests.
Each employee is a part of a certain group.

**Example:**

employee, the number of outstanding requests, belonging to a group

employee1, 4, group1

employee2, 3, group1

employee3, 5, group2

employee4, 1, group3

I'm trying to create a drop-down list of groups group1,group2,group3. Example is in the picture:

[image]

After selecting a group from the dropdown list, in the table should display rows with the corresponding value of the group.

Example:

Choose from the dropdown list value "group1"

The table should display results below:

employee, the number of outstanding requests, belonging to a group

employee1, 4, group1

employee2, 3, group1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in your sql script first. For example :

```
Select case when employee = employee1 and NoOfRequest = 4 then 'Group1'          
            when employee = employee2 and NoOfRequest = 3 then 'Group1' 
            when employee = employee3 and NoOfRequest = 5 then 'Group2'
            when employee = employee4 and NoOfRequest = 1 then 'Group3'
            end as Groupings
```

Then when you get the employee groupings you can use the `column Groupings` to filter the employee groups.

Hope this can help.